# Unable to close a child window from a parent window using console commands

Tags: batch-file, kill-process

I'm unable to close a child window from a parent window using console commands in Windows.

**Problem description**

I have three windows:

1. window x
2. window y
3. window z

**Window x** has some console commands which I need to run after opening **window y** from **window x**. Once I have done with the commands in **window x**, I need to close **window y**.

How to close **window y** once I have done with **window x** commands in Windows using console commands?

```
REM Call set environment variables
call ..\SetEnvVariables.cmd

REM Bootstrap the development environment
if exist ..\bootstrap.bat call ..\bootstrap.bat
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto BUILDERROR

echo build the server
call %SERVER_DIR%\appbuild server > server.log
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto BUILDERROR

echo calling xmlserver
REM calling xmlserver
cd %SERVER_DIR%
cd..
start xmlserver.bat
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto BUILDERROR

echo compiling the test cases
call %SERVER_DIR%\appbuild supplement -Dsupplement=tests > compiletest.log
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto BUILDERROR

call %SERVER_DIR%\appbuild database -v   > database.log
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto BUILDERROR
```

From the above code I am calling a new process i.e

```
echo calling xmlserver
REM calling xmlserver
cd %SERVER_DIR%
cd..
start xmlserver.bat
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto BUILDERROR
```

I need to close the above process i.e I am calling start xmlserver.bat.Once I have done with this:

```
call %SERVER_DIR%\appbuild database -v   > database.log
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto BUILDERROR
```

Comment: Are you using the windows command line? Do you want to write a batch script? What have you tried? Can you show us part of your code?

Comment: Hi Martin,Thanks I am using wndows command line

Comment: this is what I am doing



Window x.bat

Parent window
REM Call set environment variables
call ..\SetEnvVariables.cmd

REM Bootstrap the development environment
if exist ..\bootstrap.bat call ..\bootstrap.bat
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto BUILDERROR

REM calling xmlserver in new window(child window)
cd %SERVER_DIR%
cd..
start xmlserver.bat

call %SERVER_DIR%\appbuild server
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto BUILDERROR

Comment: Sorry Martin I am not able to format the code.

Comment: just edit your question and add the code there, while you are at it, please add the `batch-file` tag. You are right, you cannot format in comments. In the exit, mark your code with the `{}` button to format it.